# Is there non-trivial examples for groups $G$ satisfying $G = \mathrm{Aut}(G)$

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

As the question says. Are there non-trivial groups isomorphic to their automorphisms group?

(By the way i am [İbrahim İpek](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/554493/%C4%B0brahim-%C4%B0pek) but i lost the password of my account and also mail :/ Is there anything anyone can do?)

Comment: I think you can ask the moderators to merge your old and new accounts.

Comment: As for the BTW: contact the moderators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And for an example where $Z(G)\neq \{e\}$, so that the automorphism group is not just the inner automorphism group, take the Dihedral group of order $8$.

Answer (score 4):

If $G$ is a [complete group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_group#Examples), that is, with trivial center and no outer automorphisms, then $$G\simeq \text{Aut}(G)$$
as every automorphism is the conjugation by some element, and the map $g\mapsto g\cdot g^{-1}$ has a trivial kernel.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for example we have $\text{Aut}(S_n) \cong S_n$ if $n \neq 2,6$.